# Silly regexp URL matching

Tags: regex

So I want this:

`/services/auth/token`

To match this:

`http://localhost:3000/services/auth/token/` trailing / optional

but not this:

`http://localhost:3000/services/auth/token/refresh`

I'm normally better at this stuff but I'm kind of sleepy. Help SO!!!

**EDIT:**

Thanks SO, but I should've said want to do this with variables, which is what's confusing me. Forgot to add a JS tag, my apologies.

```
const myPath = '/services/auth/token';
const pathToCheck = 'http://localhost:3000/services/auth/token/';

pathToCheck.match(myPath); // doesn't work, also matches against refresh
```

Comment: `/services/auth/token/?$`

Comment: Parse the url, split on "/" (or don't) and check that *refresh* is not following *token* using `indexOf`. No regex needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid regex and use `endsWith` with 2 strings (one without trailing `/` and one with):

```js
const myPath = '/services/auth/token';
const pathToCheck = 'http://localhost:3000/services/auth/token/';

var matched = false;

// without trailinbg slash
matched = pathToCheck.endsWith(myPath);
console.log(matched);

// with trailinbg slash
matched = pathToCheck.endsWith(myPath + '/');
console.log(matched);
```

---

IE doesn’t support some of the String methods such as `String.endsWith`. To make this method work in `IE` use:

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
  };
}
```

[Reference](https://www.jyothis.co.in/2018/07/10/fix-for-javascript-string-endswith-not-supported-by-ie/)

Comment: New requirement, IE compat :S... but have an upvote for avoiding regex altogether!

Answer (score 0):

A simple negative lookahead should work here:

```
\/services\/auth\/token\/(?!refresh\b).*
```

The above pattern says to match `/services/auth/token/`, so long as what follows is not `refresh`.

### Demo

If instead you have a whitelist of accepted paths which may follow, then we can use those in place of using a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

`regex = /services\/auth\/token\/?$/`

This ensures your string must end at the optional slash following `token`.